# Difference between greedy and dynamic approach

Tags: dynamic, greedy

how are greedy and dynamic approach and how they are processed?
and can you give me any real life usage for both of them.
And how can they be used with divide and concur approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between dynamic programming and greedy approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690249/difference-between-dynamic-programming-and-greedy-approach)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage examples of greedy algorithms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867525/usage-examples-of-greedy-algorithms)

Comment: [You have a clear explanation here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18765705/3195195)